# VSTS - Building ASP.NET Core 2.0 app fails with Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.0.0 is not compatible

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up Build on VSTS for my ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app but it fails on Nuget Restore phase:

> Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>
> Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

When I was creating the build I selected App Service in Azure (or something like that). So, how can I set up Build now?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using .Net Core restore task instead.

Regarding NuGet restore, you need to user 4.3 version:

1. Add NuGet Tool Installer task (Version of NuGet.exe to install: 4.3.0)
2. NuGet restore task (Version 2.*)

Comment: Worked for me!!

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, it works... I've found NuGet Installer, but did not noticed the property of NuGet Restore task itself... Version 2.*

Comment: Answer still applies, at least for me, to fix the same error but for `netcoreapp2.2`. For me, the error only popped up in Azure Devops with a NuGet Restore (required for private feed access), but not on dotnet restore.

Comment: my issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172204/azure-devops-build-fails-for-aspnetcore-2-1-mvc-application

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Was using Nuget version 4.1.0, surprised that using 4.3.0 made a difference