# Azure DevOps Build fails for ASPNETCore 2.1 MVC application

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.1

We are using Azure DevOps and we have a build pipeline which is continous integration. When I checkin my code into Azure DevOps branch my Build pipeline kicks on and it works good.

Our company is new to .NET Core so as learning process I added ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application to my solution. Locally everything is working fine. When I check in my code my Azure DevOps build pipeline kicks off and it fails. **Our build pipeline is VS Hosted 2017 agent.**

I get below errors in Azure DevOps

```
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in D:\a\1\s\Code\MyProject\MyProject.csproj
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.9 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.9 supports:
      - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
      - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.9 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.9 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.4 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.4 supports:
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
      - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
      - portable-net45+netcore45+wp8+wp81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=wp8+netcore45+net45+wp81+wpa81)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json 1.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression 2.1.0 supports:
      - net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
      - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.Routing 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language 2.1.0 supports:
      - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
      - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.MiddlewareAnalysis 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
     Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
           Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions 2.1.0 supports:
      - net46 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6)
      - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.)
1 more errors. Click on expand view in the context menu to view complete logs.
```

**SOLUTION**

This solved my issue.

https://zimmergren.net/azure-devops-vsts-package-version-is-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp-supports-netstandard/

Comment: Nice find! I'll try and remember that if ever I run into this 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to below link which solved my issue.

https://zimmergren.net/azure-devops-vsts-package-version-is-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp-supports-netstandard/

I added new NuGet tool installer task in my Azure DevOps build pipeline. As the link says I used 4.7.1 as Version of NuGet.exe to install. After adding the task build succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try switching to the VS 2019 agents ?
Although i dont see any reason why this wouldn't work based on the dependancies installed on the VS2017 agents (1).
Microsoft does suggest using the VS2019 agents for DotNet Core development (2).

Something else to look into, are there other projects in your solution that are referencing an older version of core which might cause this conflict in versions?

1: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md

2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent

Comment: I tried with Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019. My solution only has WCF, C# class libraries, ASP.NET MVC and WinForm projects total 10 projects. I added this new 11th project ASPNETCore 2.1 MVC project.

Comment: I see Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.1.9 only in my new project. In my local VS 2019 build is good.